# how often do you expect to bring specific values?

Tags: combinatorics

If you constantly throw a couple of dice, how often do you expect to bring two $1s$?And how often do you expect to bring one $1$ and one $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you throw the first die then the probability of a one is $1/6$, right?  Same for the second die.  So if the two throws are independent (violated eg if the dice are glued together) then that probability is the product of the first two, is $1/36$.  For the second question recall that you can have either first a one and then a two or vice versa, so the probability is twice as large.

Comment: I understood the answer of the first subquestion.But could you explain me the answer of the second subquestion?? I haven't understood it!!!

Comment: You can get a 1 and then a 2 or 2 and then a 1.  Each occurs with probability $1/36$, so the probability is $2\times 1/36=1/18$.

Comment: I am confused..How did you find $2 \cdot \frac{1}{36}$ ? :/